# Dúvida simples com JQuery, suavizar efeito

Tags: jquery

Estou com dificuldades para suavizar um efeito que fiz.
Ele está muito estático, após clicar no link, o objetivo é fazer com que após o clique entre a tela de menu de uma forma suave... da opacidade 0 ao 1.

Abaixo vou deixar o código funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-nav").click(function() {
    $(".nav ul").toggleClass('nav-show');
  });
});
```

```css
.nav ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav-show {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #066;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="btn-nav">Clique aqui para Abrir</a>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="btn-nav">Clique aqui para Fechar</a>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Edição Atual</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode obter esse efeito alterando o CSS e usando o [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn-nav").click(function(){        
  $(".nav ul").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
 });
});
```

```css
.nav ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav-show {
  
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #066;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
<a href="#" class="btn-nav">Clique aqui para Abrir</a>
 <ul class="nav-show">
        <a href="#" class="btn-nav">Clique aqui para Fechar</a>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edição Atual</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu desconhecia esse método usando 'fadeToggle'